# MariaDB: SQL ERROR You have an error in your SQL syntax not a

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, mariadb

I tried to send next SQL query to MariaDB server.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES()
            MODIFIES SQL DATA
        BEGIN
        DECLARE sum1 INT;

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_yesterday ( `unuque_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `steamid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `ip` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_today ( `unuque_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `steamid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `ip` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;   
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_week ( `day1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL); 

        SET sum1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM unique_stats_week);
        IF sum1 = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO unique_stats_week (`day1`, `day2`, `day3`, `day4`, `day5`, `day6`, `day7`) VALUES ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');
        END IF;
        END //
    DELIMITER ;

CALL INIT_TABLES();
DROP PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES;
```

But got error:

> SQL ERROR You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '
> DELIMITER //
> CREATE PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES()
> MODIFIES SQL DATA
> BEGIN
> DECL
> ' at line 1!

Also, I tried to execute this SQL query in PHPMyAdmin... And this query executed without errors in syntax!

If I remove DELIMITER

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES()
            MODIFIES SQL DATA
        BEGIN
        DECLARE sum1 INT;

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_yesterday ( `unuque_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `steamid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `ip` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_today ( `unuque_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `steamid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `ip` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;   
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_week ( `day1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL); 

        SET sum1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM unique_stats_week);
        IF sum1 = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO unique_stats_week (`day1`, `day2`, `day3`, `day4`, `day5`, `day6`, `day7`) VALUES ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');
        END IF;
        END 
CALL INIT_TABLES();
DROP PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES; 

then got next error:
```

> SQL ERROR You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'CALL INIT_TABLES(); DROP PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES'
> at line 15!

I found answer:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES()
            MODIFIES SQL DATA
        BEGIN
        DECLARE sum1 INT;

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_yesterday ( `unuque_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `steamid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `ip` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_today ( `unuque_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `steamid` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `ip` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;   
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_stats_week ( `day1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `day7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL); 

        SET sum1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM unique_stats_week);
        IF sum1 = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO unique_stats_week (`day1`, `day2`, `day3`, `day4`, `day5`, `day6`, `day7`) VALUES ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');
        END IF;
        END;
CALL INIT_TABLES();
DROP PROCEDURE INIT_TABLES;
```

It works!

Comment: `DELIMITER` is command-line client command, not SQL statement.

Comment: Is it possible that the table `unique_stats_week` exists but does not contain the row specified in INSERT statement? If not then use single `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` statement instead of separate CREATE, INSERT and intermediate IF.

Comment: I need one query (no query flood)

Comment: @Akina , and how to fix my problem ? need just remove first line ?

Comment: You must (1) remove both lines with `DELIMITER` keyword (2) use execution method which performs batch code execution.

Comment: From the other side: Now you need 3 queries (create proc, execute it, drop it). W/o SP you need 3 queries too (2 CREATE TABLE and one CREATE TABLE .. SELECT). Where is the profit?

Comment: @Akina i update question. Got another problem when remove DELIMITER from query!

Comment: Why you do not read my words??? *then got next error:* Now read letter-by-letter: *Now you need **3 queries** (create proc, execute it, drop it).* 3, not 1 !!! Maybe 2 (execute and drop may be combined) - but procedure creation **MUST** be the only code in the query. PS. Rather than the 2nd method, where all 3 statements may be sent as single batch.

Comment: @Akina why? It's a waste of application resources, why can't I send this in one query, are there any alternatives? This is MariaDB limitations ?

Comment: This is batch limitation. Stored object creation  syntax limitation. It is not relative to programming language / access method. You cannot mix SP creation and additional queries - server cannot distinguish does `;` delimiter is stored object text char or statement delimiter.

Comment: @Akina Because it's works : https://pastebin.com/1XqL4xzM

Comment: Now reproduce this on real MySQL enabling general log and look SQL statements sent to MySQL really. If this works on real server than your connector is smart enough for to divide your code to separate batches.

Comment: @Akina i check, tables created and procedure executed, and removed after execute. And it works! (MariaDB) need just add ; after END. Akina bad coder! ))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. If the proposed duplicate does NOT answer your question please notify @Shadow , including some reasoning.

Comment: @Yunnosch what is @ Shadow ?? I found solution, in duplicate question no solutions! I need one big query. This is not a duplicate!

Comment: Shadow is the user who closed your question as a duplicate. If you think it is not a duplicate you could most helpfully convince to undo the close. Otherwise you have to convince three other reputated users. Adding the "@" prefix in a comment makes sure that the person reads the comment. I.e. Shadow will sooner or later find this anyway, but you should add reasoning.

Comment: @Yunnosch In another 'duplicate' question no solution.But I found answer for my question.